How to setup Git Plugin for Rundeck with multiple projects
How to setup Git Plugin for Rundeck with multiple projects where the resource files are in the same repo.
I'm getting:
The Node Source had an error:
Could not delete file D:\rundeck\projects\resources\.git\objects\pack\pack-1255248fbed36dd81cfcc5631b10fb169a5267d0.pack

The plugin is configured like:
Git / Resource ModelWritable Resource Model on a Git repository
Base Directory:D:\rundeck\projects\resources
Git URL:https://api_rundeck@stash.example.com.au/scm/repo/reponame.git
Branch:develop
Resource model File:ServerResources\DEV\DeltaServer.json
File Format: json
Writable: Yes
Git Password:••••••••••••
SSH: Strict Host Key Checking: yes

I've configured all the projects and while the repo deploys, it doesnt get updated when I push changes to it and gives this error:
Could not delete file D:\rundeck\projects\resources\.git\objects\pack\pack-1255248fbed36dd81cfcc5631b10fb169a5267d0.pack



Which Rundeck version are  you using?
Which kind of installation are you using?
Which Operating system Are you using?
Could you share your SCM config?
you're probably facing this: https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/5675
Does it work in a single project config?
Can you share the service.log  content?


Its Rundeck version 5.5.0 and hosted on Windows Server 2019. To be clear I'm using the Git Plugin, not the built in SCM stuff in rundeck as I'm using it for resource file version control, not the job definitions. Service.log has errors like:
[timestamp] ERROR resources.ExceptionCatchingResourceModelSource [NodeService-SourceLoader28] - [ResourceModelSource: 1.source (git-resource-model), project: SIT]
java.io.IOException: Could not delete file D:\rundeck\projects\resources.git\objects\pack\pack-1255248fbed36dd81cfcc5631b10fb169a5267d0.pack
....

Thanks for the clarification! After digging a bit more into this, the Git plugin is based on JGIT and I found this issue related to JGIT on Windows Operating Systems: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/293, Could you test the same in a Linux OS? (maybe in a non-prod virtualized environment). I think the plugin needs an update.

Thanks ill raise it with the developer

Also, make sure to give the correct permission to the project/git folder.

For the record: After reproducing this, give full read/write permission to the project folder, which is applied to git local subfolders and child objects, then restart the rundeck service.
